# Session variables getting unset after installing SSL through AWS Cloudfront

Tags: php, session-variables, amazon-cloudfront

I have a PHP web app on AWS EC2. There is only one instance.

I recently installed SSL through AWS certificate manager and also installed AWS Cloudfront.

Everything was working fine till I installed SSL and configured the cloud front.

Now my session variables are getting unset when I move from one php page to another

example:

### Test.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = "first";
$_SESSION['test1'] = " last";
echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="test2.php">CLICK ME</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

### Result

```
first CLICK ME
```

### Test2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];
echo $_SESSION['test1'];
?>
```

### Result

```
Test2.php prints nothing.
```

This means that the session variables got unset when I clicked on Test.php

Why is this happening? It works perfectly fine in a normal HTTP setup that I have on my local.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in AWS Cloudfront "FORWARD COOKIES" ... that needs to be set to "ALL" ... otherwise the cloud front will not go to the origin to get the object.

That solved it. thanks all.

Comment: More precisely, otherwise, CloudFront will strip the cookies, send the request to the origin, and cache that response for future requests.  For requests that don't need cookies, you don't want to forward cookies, because that will reduce the number of cache hits dramatically, so you may want to create new cache behaviors for things like `/*.png` and `/*.css` without cookie whitelisting, if they don't need authentication/sessions.